# Is there a way to retry a job that has been removed from Dead Job queue?

Tags: sidekiq

Since Sidekiq's dead job queue has a capacity of 10,000. I sometimes run Batch Job that runs Jobs for a million records at a time and the failures pop up anywhere from 10k to 20k.

Since not all of the jobs are seen in the `dead job queue`, I cannot retry all of them and have to run the maintenance task all over again.

Is there a way to re-run all of the failures either with the Sidekiq UI or with Rails console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are disabling normal retries.  Use the normal retry flow, this will work without issue.

Comment: So, is it by design that if a job gets out of the normal queues (scheduled, dead or retry), then it's no way to get hold of the job and retry it manually?

Comment: Those are the three sets where a job can be pending.  If it's not there or enqueued for execution, it is gone for good.

Comment: You can increase the max dead size but that's a hack.  Better to use Sidekiq's retry system as designed.